# selecting rows in sql in sequence fashion of column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My database structure looks like this

```
----------------------------
|id    |    col    |filter |
----------------------------
|1     |   val11   | type1 |
|2     |   val21   | type2 |
|3     |   val31   | type2 |
|4     |   val41   | type3 |
|5     |   val51   | type1 |
|6     |   val51   | type1 |
|7     |   val61   | type3 |
|8     |   val71   | type2 |
```

Now, I want to select and sort rows according to filter col such that, they should give output as follows

```
 row with type 1
 row with type 2
 row with type 3
 row with type 1
 ..............
 ..............
```

and so on.
Means in a repetitive fashion in the above sequence.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

desired output

```
----------------------------
|id    |    col    |filter |
----------------------------
|1     |   val11   | type1 |
|2     |   val21   | type2 |
|4     |   val41   | type3 |
|5     |   val51   | type1 |
|3     |   val31   | type2 |
|7     |   val61   | type3 |
|6     |   val51   | type1 |
|8     |   val71   | type2 |
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. Can you add the compelte desired output.

Comment: In what order do you want the other columns?

Comment: Your best bet is to re-order the results in code, if you insist on doing it in SQL you could probably use three variables to get row numbers, multiple the row number by 10, add the type number, then order by the result. It will be slow, more complicated than it should be, and the wrong place to do it, but if want to do it that way it is possible.

Comment: @scragar I ain't taking those odds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to cycle through the types.  The way to do this is to enumerate the types and then order by the enumeration:

```
select t.id, t.col, t.filter
from (select t.*,
             @rn := if(@f = filter, @rn + 1, if(@f := filter, 1, 1)) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @f := '', @rn := 0) vars
      order by filter, id
     ) t
order by rn, field(filter, 'type1', 'type2', 'type3');
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Also, was thinking if there is any way to add another selection parameter ? I insert WHERE col = 'value21' before order by rn but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

...or simpler but slower...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.filter = x.filter 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY id 
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(*)
     , filter;
```